# Scroll Bar Hides Automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

Maybe I didn't noticed before,or it didn't happened before.
I made a html document with different tabs , each with several sub-tabs.
With each Main Tab having different color schemes.Like First tab all-green ,second all-blue.Same applied to scroll bar.And Fixed header on top with width:100vw
But Browser scrollbar hides scroll bar if tab doesn't have enough content.
which causes viewport to increase and header width increase.And it cause disrupts viewing.Can anyone suggest a way to prevent scrollbar from hiding.
[image: Scroll Bar Showing due to enough content]
[image: Scroll Bar Hidden]
Notice the Scroll Bar

```
<body id="body" class="greenbody">

body.greenbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 10px;}
body.greenbody::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background-color:rgb(0,50,0);}
body.greenbody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background-size:10px; 
 background-image:url("../assets/ScrollGreen.png");}
body.greenbody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
 background:rgb(0,0,0);
 background-size:10px; 
 background-image:url("../assets/ScrollGreen.png");}
/*---------------------*/
body.bluebody::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 10px;}
body.bluebody::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background-color:rgb(0,0,90);}
body.bluebody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background-image:url("../assets/ScrollBlue.png");
 background-size:10px;}
body.bluebody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
 background:rgb(0,0,0);
 background-size:10px; 
 background-image:url("../assets/ScrollBlue.png");}
/*---------------------*/
body.redbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 10px;}
body.redbody::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 background-color:rgb(60,0,0);}
body.redbody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background-size:10px; 
 background-image:url("../assets/ScrollRed.png");}
body.redbody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
 background:rgb(0,0,0);
 background-size:10px; 
 background-image:url("../assets/ScrollRed.png");}
```

Down given statement includes in tab button function

```
body.className = "redbody|greenbody|bluebody";
```

anyone of them depending on tab button)
Everything else works smoothly ,just scroll bar messes up a little.
Thanks , in advance

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use the CSS property `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: However , now, i kinda fixed this by a little trick by defining:  body{height:101vh;} and forcing to add scroll-bar  @SWC

Comment: You can have a look at [webpage](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13EjxN8hq0WQk-PIjxJxKgxRfDjPOLhij) if you wish to.